# If $N = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}$ is an odd perfect number, then ${p_i}^{\alpha_i} < \sqrt{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-factorization, perfect-numbers

In this [paper](http://www.pphmj.com/abstract/7649.htm), Peter Acquaah asserts that an important difference between odd perfect and even perfect numbers is that:

> **(A)** The greatest component of an odd perfect number $N$ is less than $\sqrt{N}$.
>
> **(B)** The greatest component of an even perfect number $M$ is greater than $\sqrt{M}$.

**ATTEMPT TO PROVE STATEMENT (B)**

Let $M = {2^{p-1}}(2^p - 1)$ be an even perfect number.  Since $2^{p-1} < 2^p - 1$ and $2^p - 1$ is prime, the largest component of $M$ is the Mersenne prime $2^p - 1$.

We want to show that
$$2^p - 1 > \sqrt{M} = 2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\sqrt{2^p - 1}.$$
Assume to the contrary that
$$2^p - 1 \leq 2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\sqrt{2^p - 1}.$$
This implies that
$$\sqrt{2^p - 1} \leq 2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$$
which means
$$2^p - 1 \leq 2^{p-1}.$$
This contradicts $2^{p-1} < 2^p - 1$.

Now here is my question:

> How do you prove **Statement (A)**?

I only know that an odd perfect number (if it exists) must take the form $N = q^k n^2$ where $\gcd(q,n)=1$ and $q$ is prime (called the *Euler prime*) satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  I also know that
$$q^k < \frac{2}{3}n^2.$$
(See this [paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html) for a proof.)

Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blimey, I didn't realize that the answer to my question is in my [thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1450).

In particular, if
$$N = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}$$
is the canonical factorization of an odd perfect number $N$, then one of the results in my thesis states that
$$\sigma({p_i}^{\alpha_i}) \leq \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{N}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}$$
for all $i$, $1 \leq i \leq \omega(N)$.  (This has since been continually improved by several authors.)

In particular,
$${p_i}^{\alpha_i} < \sigma({p_i}^{\alpha_i}) \leq \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{N}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}} < \frac{N}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}.$$
This implies that ${p_i}^{\alpha_i} < \sqrt{N}$ for all $i$.

**QED**